# No component for supporting the service CMS.Helpers.ICurrentCookieLevelProvider was found

Tags: kentico, kentico-11

Hi I am having a kentico 11 website. I am getting following error when am trying host and run it locally from IIS

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
No component for supporting the service CMS.Helpers.ICurrentCookieLevelProvider was found
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service CMS.Helpers.ICurrentCookieLevelProvider was found

Source Error:


Line 16:     protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
Line 17:     {
Line 18:         base.OnPreRender(e);
Line 19: 
Line 20:         lblText.Text = "The web site doesn't contain any content. Sign in to <a href=\"" + ResolveUrl("~/Admin/cmsadministration.aspx") + "\">administration</a> and edit the content.";

Source File: \CMS\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 18

Stack Trace:


[ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service CMS.Helpers.ICurrentCookieLevelProvider was found]
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, Arguments arguments, IReleasePolicy policy, Boolean ignoreParentContext) +144
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, Arguments arguments) +40
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve() +69
   CMS.Core.IoCContainer.Resolve() +93

[ServiceResolutionException: Resolution of 'CMS.Helpers.ICurrentCookieLevelProvider' failed with the following error: No component for supporting the service CMS.Helpers.ICurrentCookieLevelProvider was found]
   CMS.Core.IoCContainer.Resolve() +262
   CMS.Helpers.CookieHelper.IsCookieAllowedInternal(String name) +38
   CMS.Helpers.CookieHelper.GetValueInternal(String name, Boolean useDefaultValue, Boolean allowSensitiveData) +397
   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.GetCurrentStylesheet(PageInfo pageInfo) +87
   CMS.UIControls.DocumentBase.get_CurrentStylesheet() +31
   CMS.UIControls.DocumentBase.SetCSS() +21
   CMS.UIControls.DocumentBase.PreRender() +44
   _Default.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) in \CMS\Default.aspx.cs:18
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +132
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4005
```

Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of CMS libraries may be missing. How did you setup the website: did you install Kentico or got the code and database backup? Check the missing references in CMS project in Visual Studio, clean, rebuild and try again.